# Centre divs within a column in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm trying to place two divs within a column into the centre of the page so that there is little to no space in-between them. The top row is fine, but the bottom row is causing me issue. I'd like to keep the logos the same size as the first row and centre them together. I've shown what this looks like below. Code attached. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
  <div class="col-md-12 vertical-center" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                        <a href="http://www.msh.on.ca/" target="_blank">
                            <img alt="hosp-logo" class="img-responsive center-block hosp-logo" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" src="images/hosp-1.png">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                        <a href="http://www.tegh.on.ca/bins/index.asp" target="_blank">
                            <img alt="hosp-logo" class="img-responsive center-block hosp-logo" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" src="images/hosp-2.png"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                        <a href="http://www.southlakeregional.org/" target="_blank">
                            <img alt="hosp-logo" class="img-responsive center-block hosp-logo" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" src="images/hosp-3.png"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                        <a href="https://www.niagarahealth.on.ca/site/home" target="_blank">
                            <img alt="hosp-logo" class="img-responsive center-block hosp-logo" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" src="images/hosp-4.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="col-md-12 vertical-center" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
                    <div class="col-md-3 center-block">
                        <a href="https://www.niagarahealth.on.ca/site/home" target="_blank">
                            <img alt="hosp-logo" class="img-responsive center-block hosp-logo" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" src="images/hosp-4.png"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 center-block">
                        <a href="https://www.niagarahealth.on.ca/site/home" target="_blank">
                            <img alt="hosp-logo" class="img-responsive center-block hosp-logo" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" src="images/hosp-4.png"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Use Flexbox. You will be able to align the elements as you need.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this html with few modifications:

```
    <div class="col-md-12 vertical-center" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
    <a href="http://www.msh.on.ca/" target="_blank">
      <img alt="hosp-logo" class="img-responsive center-block hosp-logo" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" src="images/hosp-1.png">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
    <a href="http://www.tegh.on.ca/bins/index.asp" target="_blank">
      <img alt="hosp-logo" class="img-responsive center-block hosp-logo" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" src="images/hosp-2.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
    <a href="http://www.southlakeregional.org/" target="_blank">
      <img alt="hosp-logo" class="img-responsive center-block hosp-logo" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" src="images/hosp-3.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
    <a href="https://www.niagarahealth.on.ca/site/home" target="_blank">
      <img alt="hosp-logo" class="img-responsive center-block hosp-logo" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" src="images/hosp-4.png"></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 vertical-center text-center" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
  <div class="col-md-6 center-block">
    <a href="https://www.niagarahealth.on.ca/site/home" target="_blank">
      <img alt="hosp-logo" class="img-responsive center-block hosp-logo" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" src="images/hosp-4.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 center-block">
    <a href="https://www.niagarahealth.on.ca/site/home" target="_blank">
      <img alt="hosp-logo" class="img-responsive center-block hosp-logo" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" src="images/hosp-4.png"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Modified HTML:

```
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 vertical-center text-center" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
  <div class="col-md-6 center-block">
    <a href="https://www.niagarahealth.on.ca/site/home" target="_blank">
      <img alt="hosp-logo" class="img-responsive center-block hosp-logo" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" src="images/hosp-4.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 center-block">
    <a href="https://www.niagarahealth.on.ca/site/home" target="_blank">
      <img alt="hosp-logo" class="img-responsive center-block hosp-logo" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" src="images/hosp-4.png"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/2191/

Comment: This is perfect - can you walk me through how this offset is working to keep the images the same size as the md-3's above?

Comment: @Zack here is the docs for offset: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-offsetting . Let me know if you need more explanation